# Advantage of wrapping in monad

Tags: haskell, monads

Look at `mapM` function:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable (t :: * -> *) where
  ...
  mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

As you can see, the result is in the monad context.
What is the sense, that `t b` get wrapped in the monad? What kind of power do I get of that?

Comment: What do you mean? The first argument has signature `(a -> m b)` so you can not *unwrap* the `b` out of `m b`.

Comment: Why `m (t b)` not only `m b`?

Comment: Because you map some sort of "collection" of `a`s to a collection of `b`s.

Comment: There can be many `a`s within a `t a` and therefore many `m b`s produced by `mapM` so which `b` do you want in the result? `mapM` gives you a `t b` with the same shape as the input `t a`.

Comment: If `t` is `[]`, you get back a list wrapped in the monad. If `t` is `Maybe`, you get back a `Maybe` value wrapped in the monad.

Comment: In the second comment you ask about one thing but your question is about another. What do you ask exactly?

Comment: Do you know what a traversable type is?

Comment: `mapM` is kind of old-fashioned; most people these days use `traverse`. The idea is that if I have a container full of values of type `a`, and a function `f :: a -> m b` that lets me "do something" with a value of type `a` to produce a value of type `b`, then I can use `traverse f` to "do something" with each element of the container and produce a container containing all of the results.

Answer (score 3):

I think, it is not about a power, but usefulness.

You could use `map` over some `action :: a -> m b`, but then you'd get a `[m b]` (if we forget about a `Traversable` for a moment). The `mapM` does basically the same, but also converts `[m b]` into `m [b]` by performing each action sequentially and collecting results. The last operation is called `sequence`, BTW.